# Throwing 10 dice having equal ones and fives

Tags: probability

We have 10 normal dice and we throw them at once.What is the probability that the number of ones is equal to the number of fives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample space consists of 10x six-faced dices, so there is a total of ${6^{10}} = {\text{60,466,176}}$ outcomes.
The events you're interested in are 15, 11 55, 111 555, 1111 5555 or 11111 55555. (one, two, three, four or five *pairs* of numbers).

Let the probability of getting exactly *one of such pair* be $P\left( {one} \right)$, it can be written as the probability to get exactly one, five then any other values except those in the other 8 dice (2, 3, 4 or 6 = 4 options): $$P\left( {one} \right) = {4^8}$$

It follows, then:
$$\eqalign{
  & P\left( {two} \right) = {4^6}  \cr 
  & P(three) = {4^4}  \cr 
  & P\left( {four} \right) = {4^2}  \cr 
  & P(five) = 1 \cr} $$
 Which ammounts to
$$P = \frac{{{4^8} + {4^6} + {4^4} + {4^2} + 1}}{{{\text{60,466,176}}}} = \frac{{65,536 + 4,096 + 256 + 16 + 1}}{{{\text{60,466,176}}}}$$
$$P = \frac{{69,905}}{{60,466,176}} \approx 0.0012$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Compute the probability of getting zero ones or fives, the probability of getting exactly one of each, exactly two, exactly three, exactly four, and exactly five, and add up all those probabilities.